# Find the last added file (boost)

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to build a function that finds the last added file with a specific extension. 
Here's what I did:

```
void getLastAdded(const fs::path path)
{
  const string& ext = ".xml";
  fs::path last;
  vector<fs::path> files;

  fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(path);
  fs::recursive_directory_iterator endit; 
  while (it != endit)
  {
    if (fs::is_regular_file(*it) && it->path().extension() == ext)
      files.push_back(it->path());
    ++it;
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
    if (i == 0)
      last = files[i];
    if (fs::last_write_time(last) <= fs::last_write_time(files[i]))
      last = files[i];
  }

  cout << "Last:" << last.filename() << endl;
}
```

Is there any better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Well, better is a personal choice sometimes, but my take is to use journalled file system services. It's more complicated, but performs better and can be fashioned to respond to the event when it happens rather than poll for it after the fact. The concept is, however, very platform specific (doing it in Windows is completely different than in Linux/UNIX). It also requires the disk volume is formatted in a compatible format (which, by default, is usually the case in modern systems, but not for CD/DVD and typical USB flash jump drives). If you need very general method, you're on the right track

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "how to improve this code" belongs on CodeReview.SE; StackOverflow deals with factual problems.

Comment: @MSalters "too broad" would also be applicable ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of building a (potentially huge) vector of filenames that you won't use/need, I'd filter for the max modification time on-the-fly.

Moreover, don't forget to handle errors:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

fs::path getLastAdded(const fs::path path, std::string const& ext = ".xml") {
    std::vector<fs::path> files;

    namespace pt = boost::posix_time;
    pt::ptime max = {pt::neg_infin};
    fs::path last;

    for (fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(path), endit; it != endit; ++it)
        if (fs::is_regular_file(*it) && it->path().extension() == ext)
        {
            try {
                auto stamp = pt::from_time_t(fs::last_write_time(*it));
                if (stamp >= max) {
                    last = *it;
                    max = stamp;
                }
            } catch(std::exception const& e) {
                std::cerr << "Skipping: " << *it << " (" << e.what() << ")\n";
            }
        }

    return last; // empty if no file matched
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Last: " << getLastAdded(".") << "\n";
}
```

With some debug information on Coliru:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be44f28f2617a304)</kbd>**

Prints

```
DEBUG: "./i.xml"
DEBUG: "./z.xml"
DEBUG: "./q.xml"
DEBUG: "./c.xml"
DEBUG: "./v.xml"
DEBUG: "./f.xml"
DEBUG: "./t.xml"
DEBUG: "./d.xml"
DEBUG: "./a.xml"
DEBUG: "./b.xml"
DEBUG: "./e.xml"
DEBUG: "./u.xml"
DEBUG: "./p.xml"
DEBUG: "./g.xml"
DEBUG: "./x.xml"
DEBUG: "./y.xml"
DEBUG: "./j.xml"
DEBUG: "./h.xml"
DEBUG: "./o.xml"
DEBUG: "./m.xml"
DEBUG: "./s.xml"
DEBUG: "./w.xml"
DEBUG: "./l.xml"
DEBUG: "./n.xml"
DEBUG: "./r.xml"
DEBUG: "./k.xml"
Last: "./k.xml"
```